# In WPF RichTextBox, does overriding of Underline/Strikethrough work?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, underline

In a WPF `RichTextBox`, the effective style of a `Run` of text is a result of combining the properties defined on the `Run` with the properties it "inherits" from the enclosing `Paragraph` and finally the styles on the `Document`. So you can set `FontWeight` to `Bold` at any of those levels. You can also set it `Bold` on the `Paragraph` and then switch it to `Normal` (override it) for a specific `Run`.

However, underline and strikethrough are different. They are items that can optionally appear in a list of `TextDecorations`, which is a property of `Inline` (and hence `Run`) and of `Paragraph`, but not of `Document`. And you can switch on `Underline` in the `Paragraph`, and it gets inherited so that all `Run`s within that `Paragraph` default appear underlined by default.

Is it possible to switch it off underline in a specific `Run`? i.e. is there a way to insert an entry into the list of `TextDecorations` which would mean "*Don't* underline", thus overriding the `Paragraph`'s setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you can basically handle the underline like this:

```
protected void ContinueRoutingCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
            else if (e.Command == EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                e.CanExecute = true;
                e.ContinueRouting = false;
                return;
            }
}
```

However, in your case, you want to override it only in a specific Run, right? Then, you can verify your Run inside the inner if and block it exactly like this if you want.